# How to attach a control to another control in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, layout

I have a `ListBox` at the bottom right side of my window, and I want to place a `Label` at the leftmost top side of this `ListBox`.

Currently I am using a `DockPanel` to dock the `ListBox` to the bottom right side of the window, but I am not sure how to "group" the Label and the `ListBox` together so they stay together.

Do I have to accomplish this with hardcoded margins for both so they appear they are attached together?

Also what control should I use to do this? `StackPanel`, `DockPanel`, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nest another DockPanel. Put your Label as the first child, and dock it to top. Put your ListBox as the second child; it will fill the remaining space.

```
<DockPanel Name="YourExistingDockPanel">
    ...
    <DockPanel>
        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="YourLabel"/>
        <ListBox .../>
    </DockPanel>
    ...
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks I did this But the label still stays at the way top of the window and the listbox seems centred. But both looking like they are docked to the right side of the screen.

Comment: Or do I need to set the height of the DockPanel?

Comment: Joe has the right approach to making Label and ListBox into a unit. The rest depends on how you embed this DockPanel in the rest of the UI. Inside the outer Dockpanel you have Dock=Right but no 'BottomRight'

Comment: Thanks Henk, so I should use Horizontal/VerticalAlignment for Right/Bottom for the outer DockPanel?

Comment: Also I now realized I also need to attach 2 buttons at the bottom, side by side. So it's gonna be 3 separate sections vertically for the label, listbox and the 2 buttons. Can I do this with the DockPanel?

Comment: This doesn't do anything for me. But the other answer (Jon's) kinda works.

Answer (score 3):

Put both controls in a one-cell `Grid`, and set the `Margin` property on each to position them absolutely within the cell. This will allow you to "glue" the two controls together (you control their size and their position within the cell, so glued) inside the `Grid`, which will function as the "grouper".

You can then use any way you want (e.g. `DockPanel`) to position the grid wherever you like. The two controls inside will move but always stay together.

If you do not require pixel-perfect absolute positioning, the same technique will also work if you use a `StackPanel` instead of a `Grid`. In this case, you will be limited by the layouts achievable with a `StackPanel`.

Comment: Thanks, so the Grid will be inside the DockPanel? Also why use absolute positions?

Comment: Hard-coding a margin seems like a bad idea. If you hard-code a margin, it won't update if the font changes or the text wraps. Plus, you have to guess at the right margin.

Comment: @Joan: I 've expanded on the answer.

Comment: @Joe: that's the only way to achieve complex layered layouts though. I 've expanded the answer to address the case where you don't need to do that, though.

Comment: Is it a coincidence that all of our names start with J? :O

Comment: @Jon: "Only" way? Composition (panels inside panels) works just fine, and without the drawbacks of hard-coding a margin size in pixels. I've seen a lot of people positioning things with margins instead of panels, but honestly I don't see the appeal.